# Proxy + Tor = anonymous?

Tags: proxy, tor, anonymity

I've been doing some research about how to stay anonymous on the net, and I was wondering what if you set up for instance your browser, to run through a proxy and then run through Tor? Can I browse safely that way? - I am aware that most things can be cracked, bypassed, exploited, etc. (and we all know the onion routing protocol is not as anonymous as we may think). Also I don't trust VPNs / don't know of any trustworthy.

Comment: Wondering why you don't trust any VPN providers but trust proxy providers?

Comment: @NeilSmithline Because proxy providers can facilitate less info about me I guess. If I pay for a VPN chances are that they can disclose more about me

Comment: Many VPN providers allow anonymous registration and payment with bitcoin. There are also free, public VPNs. And both proxy and VPN providers can log your IP and all data that you send.

Comment: @NeilSmithline Yeah, I guess you're right. I guess I didn't trust VPN bc of my ignorance mostly. I didn't think bitcoin was that extended tbh. Thanks!

Comment: Also now I see why my question got downvoted - http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/is-x-secure-question-anti-pattern . Sorry guys

Comment: Search the site for "tor AND vpn", you'll find similar questions.

Comment: Thanks! I did search for tor and proxy but I didn't found what I was looking for.

Comment: If you're talking about free proxies (because you mention you do not want to leave payment information): They are not anonymous. Many of them are not intentionally public at all (so you're using for example an unsecured company proxy server), others may do all sort of evil (like bad tor exit nodes, but the proxies know your IP as well). For all of them you should suspect they are logging (as it is default in most proxy softwares), while tor does not log by design and VPN providers promise not to log in their privacy policy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no real *qualitative* difference between a VPN and a proxy -- the difference is mostly quantitative. An HTTP proxy is a proxy for the HTTP protocol; a VPN is a proxy for TCP/IP and everything that can be conveyed within TCP/IP, including (but not only) HTTP. From an *anonymity* point of view, the proxy or VPN transfers the traffic that goes through it, and "sees" the source IP address and the data contents. If the data is encrypted (SSL...), the proxy or VPN can still see who talks to who, and the size of the exchanges.

Tor can be conceptually viewed as a randomly selected chain of proxies, with nested layers of encryption so that each proxy sees as little as possible. Adding an extra proxy does not really change the game. Arguably, using a Tor chain with one extra node would be better for anonymity, because, contrary to your manual proxy configuration, that extra node will be randomly selected and an extra nested layer of encryption will be applied.